# C++ Threads + Networking, accept fails as soon as I introduce threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking

I am trying to implement a small c++ server. i want to receive connections from clients, and handle all of these connections in own threads. So far so good. As long as i introduce no threads, it works fine, but as soon as i try to create a thread for a client, accept returns with -1/error.

Here is my code:

```
void Server::run()
{
  cout << "starting server on port " << this->port << "..." << endl;

  this->socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (this->socket_fd < 0) {
    perror("creating socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
  myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  myaddr.sin_port = htons(this->port);
  inet_aton("192.168.201.58", &myaddr.sin_addr);

  if ( bind(this->socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr))) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (listen(this->socket_fd, 5)) {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* waiting for clients */
  cout << "waiting for connection..." << endl;
  int client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;
  socklen_t remote_addr_len;

  while (this->running) {
    client_fd = accept(this->socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&remote_addr, &remote_addr_len);
    if (client_fd <= 0) {
        perror("accept");
        this->running = false;
        continue;
    }

    cout << "got new client with address " << inet_ntoa(remote_addr.sin_addr) << endl;

    Client new_client(client_fd, remote_addr.sin_addr);
    //new_client.run();
    std::thread t ( &Client::run, &new_client );
    //t.detach(); 
  }
}
```

when I am trying to connect via telnet, I get "accept: Invalid argument". As soon as I comment out the line where I create the thread

```
    std::thread t ( &Client::run, &new_client );
```

everything works fine.

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: You are passing the thread that address of an object that is about to go out of scope. By the time the thread runs, `new_client` may not exist any more. Two obvious solutions: 1) Use a `make_shared` to create the client object and pass the thread  a `shared_ptr` to it. 2) Pass the thread the descriptor and address by value and let the thread create the client object.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! So i changed new_client to dynamically allociated: `while (this->running) {
  client_fd = accept(this->socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&remote_addr, &remote_addr_len);
  if (client_fd <= 0) {
   perror("accept");
   this->running = false;
   continue;
  }

  Client *new_client = new Client(client_fd, remote_addr.sin_addr);
 }
` and removed the thread. Still the same problem that accept fails.

Comment: You need to initialize `remote_addr_len` before each call to `accept`.

Comment: thats it @DavidSchwartz ! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
std::thread t ( &Client::run, std::move(new_client) );
```

According to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), that's how you should call it.

Comment: I assume you mean `std::thread t ( &Client::run, std::ref(new_client) );` otherwise I get an compiler error. But anyway, both variants don't solve the issue.

Comment: What is the thread supposed to do with a reference to an object that no longer exists?

Comment: Yeah, fixed the & missing. Also, I am pretty sure that if you use std::move instead, it will solve the problem of new_client going out of scope.